# Implement something like reference counting in SQLite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, orm

The problem concerns two SQLite database tables:
`persons` and `measurements`.

One person can have many measurements, but each measurement has only one person. So it is a 1:M relationship between person and measurement.

I already have a list which shows all persons. The database entities from the `persons` table are converted to person objects by my self-written object relational mapping class, then the person names are shown in the list.

Now I have to expand the list to show not only the person names but also the number of measurements for each person.

One list entry should look like this:

```
Person XY
2 Measurements
```

One approach would be to make a separate `COUNT` query for each person just before the list is shown. However, this would be a really inefficient and bad solution.

Another approach would be to add a `ref_count` column to the persons table, which has to contain the number of related measurements.

If feels like a relational database has a bad structure for problems like this. How should I implement the list?

Comment: for the SQLite part: I suppose both tables have a column for the person 'id'. Why don't you do an inner join giving you the name and COUNT using the person 'id'? - for the android part: please post your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relational databases are fine for this sort of use.

Where you query your persons table you need to change the query to include the count of items in the measurements table for each person.  Something like this;

```
SELECT PersonName, Count(Measurements.ID) AS NumberOfMeasurements
FROM Persons LEFT JOIN Measurements on Measurements.PersonID = Persons.ID
GROUP BY Persons.ID, Persons.PersonName
```

That will give you two columns in your resulting cursor, the persons name and a count of measurements called NumberOfMeasurements.  My SQL may not be exact but the count, join and group by are the important bits.  Note that all fields you return from the Persons table must be included in the group by.

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) site for details

Comment: Thank you for your help. Should I add a ref_count to my `person` class in order to store the resulting count of `NumberOfMeasurements`? The problem is that this ref_count member would be only a temporary information, which should not be persistent in `person` objects.

Comment: Yes, add a ref_count field to your person class and populate it from the above query.  When you come to save your person class to the database via an Insert or Update then just ignore that field.  It's unclear from your question if you are using some sort of DAO library.  If you are then there should be a way of excluding a field from being saved, usually an attribute on the field.

Comment: This query is efficient if there is an index on `Measurements.PersonID`.

Comment: @CL  Agreed though if there are only a few dozen entries it would make little difference though it's always good practice to put indexes on foreign keys.

Comment: No I do not use any DAO library, it is a self-written class. What exactly do you mean with an index on foreign keys in SQLite? Currently I just use the `REFERS(persons.personID)` clause.

Comment: The Reference sets up a constraint to say that the person must exist for a measurement.  An Index will make finding all measurements for a person faster when dealing with large amounts of data as it will use the index rather than read through all measurements.  After your CREATE TABLE statements you should add something like  CREATE INDEX MeasurementsPersonIndex ON Measurements(personId); See http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes